# Access control with a very large AD group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, security, active-directory, performance

I'm working with a company that has 100k+ employees, contractors, and external partners who have user accounts in their Active Directory. People fall into different categories:

- Employees (60k)
- Contractors (20k)
- Offshore Partners (10k)
- Research Partner 1 (5k)
- Research Partner 2 (5k)
- etc

In SharePoint, read-only access is being provisioned by enabling access for *All Authenticated Users*. Up to now this has been OK, but there are an increasing number of external partners who should have more limited access. In essence it would be best to have a group including just employees and contractors.

It has been proposed that an Active Directory group is created containing the ~80k users, and that this is used when tighter control than all authenticated users is required. I'm concerned that there might be a performance impact.

1. Has anyone encountered a situation like this? Is there a better way
   to handle this?
2. Does SharePoint 2010 efficiently search large AD groups to identify membership?
3. Have Microsoft published any guidance on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

**Definitely use Active Directory security groups!**

Since one AD group only takes up one security object (no matter how many members), they are much better than assigning individual users SharePoint permissions.

> You can add users individually to SharePoint groups, or you can take
>   advantage of Active Directory by adding entire security groups (such
>   as adding the Sales_Dept security group as members of the Sales site
>   collection). This is a good thing from a Windows SharePoint Services
>   administrative point of view, because Windows SharePoint Services can
>   only handle so many security objects (otherwise known as security
>   principals). As far as Windows SharePoint Services is concerned, both
>   a single user account and a security group are security objects, even
>   though the security group can contain many user accounts.

Source: [Chapter 11: Users and Permissions (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728295%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

However, I would also recommend some reading on [Marc Anderson's](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/82/marc-d-anderson) blog.

- [Active Directory Groups vs. SharePoint Groups for User Management: A Dilemma](http://sympmarc.com/2011/02/16/active-directory-groups-vs-sharepoint-groups-for-user-management-a-dilemma/)
- [Active Directory Groups vs. SharePoint Groups for User Management: The Denouement](http://sympmarc.com/2011/02/22/active-directory-groups-vs-sharepoint-groups-for-user-management-the-denouement/)

The main issue with AD groups is *administration*. It usually is very easy to add users to SharePoint. On the other hand, Active Directory is usually locked down to a few admins or a security team.

In your case, this probably is actually a *benefit* because the groups are already provisioned and you just need to use them.

I can speak from experience that when you start syncing many, many users to a site collection it does not end well (ex: site no longer can be crawled for search).